# pass global variables as parameter in a function or initialise it in constructor

Tags: php, oop

Let's say that we have a FruitFactory class that it creates fruit based on the query parameter **$type** that can be accessed globally.

Which one of the following approaches is better ? ( or if there is another approach that is better let me know ).

Does it make sense to pass a global variable as a parameter in a function ? ( like in the first approach )

Or is it better to just call the function and let it be responsible for the global variable **type**.

```
class FruitFactory
{

    public function create($type)
    {
        if($type == 'Apple')
        {
            return new Apple();
        }
    }
}

$fruit = new FruitFactory();
$type = $_GET['type'];
$result = $fruit->create($type);
```

Or

```
class FruitFactory
{
   protected $type;
   public function __construct()
    {
         $this->type = $_GET['type'];
    }

    public function create()
    {
        if($this->type == 'Apple')
        {
            return new Apple();
        }
    }
}

$fruit = new FruitFactory();

$result = $fruit->create();
```

Comment: Which Factory can you test automated?

Comment: I guess the first approach since the $type is passed as a parameter in the create method ( correct me if I'm wrong )

Comment: The second version is bad, as it is tightly coupled to user input in the context of a webserver query. Your first version is a lot more solid (outside of the fact that the `create` function should always return something or throw an error).

Comment: Indeed :) Be carefull though with opinion-based questions.

Comment: what if there is a third version where I pass the global variable in the constructor as a parameter. I guess I can still test that since I cannot even instantiate an object without passing that parameter in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is the better implementation for quite a few reason. The one specific to your question is in regards to flexibility. The first example simply requires a type value (which can come from anywhere, including global state). While the second example requires a specific global state value, making it much less flexible in its use.